# android - Cannot resolved symbol PlusShare

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-plus, android-studio-import

I follow this [Google link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/) to make a sharing function in my application. However, Android studio `cannot resolved symbol PlusShare` in the sample code.

My google play service is updated to the newest version (Rev 32).

I also have this line in my gradle:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'`

If I am missing anything in my code, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "if I am missing anything in my code..:", so show us your code..... :)

Answer (score 1):

After all the answer here by the other community, I can't see the cause of that problem. So just make sure you set up the [Google Play service](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) properly in your android, especially the different Google Play services API that you need in your build.gradle

example:

- Google+  - `com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.4.0`
- Google Account Login - `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0`

And what can I give you is another sample code or tutorials on how to make sharing to Google+ from your android app.

This tutorials can explain you the steps that you need in order to integrate Google+ in your Android.

- [Integrating Google Plus Sign In into your Android Application](http://androidsrc.net/integrating-google-plus-sign-in-into-your-android-application/)
- [Google Plus Integration in Android](http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.com/2013/05/google-plus-integration-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

Installed/Updated Google Play Services, and Google Repository from SDK Manager

Add dependency in build.gradle:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
```

Update AndroidManifest.xml with

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: I tried it, but Android Studio still cannot resolved symbol `PlusShare`. Do you have other suggestion? Do I need to add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your build.gradle dependencies `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.2.0'`

Make sure that you're using latest version of Android Studio with updated Google play services. If at all the above dependencies create another error you can use the latest one in your gradle `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.2.1'`

Comment: I tried it, but Android studio still cannot resolved the symbol `PlusShare`. Do you have other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your dependency

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```